# How to add hover animation to an already animated image link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I have an 'ul' of image links animated to move constantly, and I'd like to know if there's a way to add another animation when a mouse hovers over them.

Images are placed in divs and scaled down to div size, I'd like to have them zoom in on hover, without stopping the original animation.

I already tried everything I could think of, but I've only just started using jQuery, and I can't figure this one out.

Here's the link: 
http://cqweblab.com/azbuka/azbuka.html

And the code.
HTML:

```
<div id="azbuka">
<ul class="slova">
<li><img src="images/1.png" class="space"></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/a.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/b.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/v.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/g.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/d.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/dj.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/e.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/zj.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/z.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/i.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/j.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/k.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/l.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/lj.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/m.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/n.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/nj.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/o.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/p.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/r.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/s.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/t.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/cj.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><img src="images/3.png" class="space"></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/u.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/f.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/h.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/c.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/ch.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/dz.png" class="firstAnim"></a></div></li>
<li><div class="letter"><a href="#"><img src="images/sj.png" class="secondAnim"></a></div></li>
```

The CSS:

```
#azbuka {
width: 24.2em;
height: 11em;
margin: 10em auto 2em auto;
}

.letter {
width: 3em;
height: 2.81em;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

ul.slova {
list-style-type: none;
}

ul.slova li a img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

img.space {
position: relative;
float: left;    
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
function endlessFst(item) {
      $(item).animate({"width" : "95%" , "opacity" : "0.7"}, 700, function(){
        $(item).animate({"width" : "100%" , "opacity" : 1}, 700);
        endlessFst(item);
      });
    }

function endlessSnd(item) {
      $(item).delay(100).animate({"width" : "95%" , "opacity" : "0.7"}, 700, function(){
        $(item).delay(100).animate({"width" : "100%" , "opacity" : 1}, 700);
        endlessSnd(item);
      });
    }

    endlessFst($(".letter a img.firstAnim"));   
    endlessSnd($(".letter a img.secondAnim"));
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your link isnt working - its showing a "This page is currently being reviewed" message

Comment: Sorry. I changed it, this one should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just listen in to your img's hover event

```
$("ul.slova li a img").hover(function() {
    //do animation
    $(this).animate({
        height: "50%"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
}, function() {
    //undo animation
    $(this).animate({
        height: "100%"
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx, Keith! This works great. ..After i added it, I needed to animate the width of the img too, which was already being animated, but I solved that by adding another div around each img. Kinda messy, but it did the job.  Thank you!

Comment: @shki Can you mark this as the correct answer is this has helped you.